# Content inset on UITableView

Tags: uitableview, ios6, xcode5

I'm trying to set the content inset in a tableview to leave a white space on top. I'm using the following code:

```
CGRect fr = tView.frame;
fr.origin.y = 0;
tView.frame = fr;
[tView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 40, 0)];
```

The top space does not seem to be working. I'm using xcode5-dp5, it was working on DP4. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did the answer help or is the question still open? This should be working on the production version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you want to set the a rectangle inset within another you should consider using the following method:

```
CGRectInset(<#CGRect rect#>, <#CGFloat dx#>, <#CGFloat dy#>);
```

So for example you might achieve your objective by

```
CGRect fr = CGRectInset(tView.frame,40,40);
```

Quick help describes this function as:

Returns a rectangle that is smaller or larger than the source rectangle, with the same center point.
The rectangle is standardized and then the inset parameters are applied. If the resulting rectangle would have a negative height or width, a null rectangle is returned.

**Parameters**
rect - The source CGRect structure.

dx - 
The x-coordinate value to use for adjusting the source rectangle. To create an inset rectangle, specify a positive value. To create a larger, encompassing rectangle, specify a negative value.

dy - 
The y-coordinate value to use for adjusting the source rectangle. To create an inset rectangle, specify a positive value. To create a larger, encompassing rectangle, specify a negative value.

Returns

A rectangle. The origin value is offset in the x-axis by the distance specified by the dx parameter and in the y-axis by the distance specified by the dy parameter, and its size adjusted by (2*dx,2*dy), relative to the source rectangle. If dx and dy are positive values, then the rectangle’s size is decreased. If dx and dy are negative values, the rectangle’s size is increased.